# c# linq to xml error: cannot implicitly convert type

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm getting the following error:

**Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable to System.Xml.Linq.XElement. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

I have an XML file that looks something like:

```
<Users xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/directory/"> 
<User ID="91" Name="Jane Smith" LoginName="domain1\jsmith" />
<User ID="814" Name="Brad Jones" LoginName="domain1\bjones" />
<User ID="1252" Name="Charles Johnson" LoginName="domain2\cjohnson" />
</Users>
```

I want to select the node with a particular ID. Here's my code (the Where clause gives the error):

```
XmlNode siteUsers = tempug.GetUserCollectionFromSite();
string innerXML = siteUsers.InnerXml;
XDocument siteUserData = XDocument.Parse(innerXML);
XElement userNode = siteUserData.Descendants("User")
  .Where(n => n.Attribute("ID").Value.Equals("12");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
XElement userNode = siteUserData.Descendants("User")
  .Where(n => n.Attribute("ID").Value.Equals("12").FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
XElement userNode = siteUserData.Descendants("User")
  .Where(n => n.Attribute("ID").Value.Equals("12").SingleOrDefault();
```

you can use `Single()` and `First()` aswell, depending on how strict you want the return to be.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `.Where` in your last line to `.SingleOrDefault`

Answer (score 2):

`.Where()` will return an `IEnumerable` even if there is only one item in it. If you're expecting only one item to be returned you can call `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()` on the **Enumerable**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell linq you only want 1 node

```
var userNode = siteUserData.Descendants("User")
  .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Attribute("ID").Value.Equals("12"));
```